# Open message box if row cells in a particular column are clicked

Tags: c#, datagridview

How would I open up a message box if row cells in a particular column are clicked?

This is my code so far - I'm trying to open up a **hello** message box each time a cell in the Account column is pressed.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Account")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: well, looks like it should work, what's the result you got?

Comment: The program builds but nothing happens when I click on cells in the Account column

Comment: @methuselah please be sure your `CellClick` handler is subscribed correctly, otherwise of course it will do nothing for you.

Comment: Try adding `Console.WriteLine(this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)` before your `if` statement and click the cell you want this to work for. Ensure the name being printed to the console matches what you're expecting (`Account`).

Comment: Like Grant Winney said, place a breakpoint on the IF statement itself. See what the `Name` property's value actually is

Comment: I'm sure that you did not subscribe event handler for `CellClick`, because your method has wrong signature to match a `CellClick` event handler. the argument should be `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` not `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs`, trying to subscribe that method will show some error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code in an application and what i've found was that the EventArgs was different from mine.

Mine looks like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
```

and it works. You should try to check your EventArgs type because it differs from mine.

EDIT: Like King king said in the comments, you have to subscribe the event too (if not already done) You can do it by clicking your DataGridview in design mode, showing its properties (F4) and double clicking CellClick. When you do it, the new event will appear on your form class and you can put the same code you wrote above inside the new event.

Comment: yes, I think this is not enough because looks like the OP even does not know how to subscribe the event handler, you should add that part in your answer.

Comment: How do you do this on VS2013?